# Генерация карты шума

Tags: c#

Я хочу сделать генерацию огромной карты при помощи любого шума, можно и перлина и симплекс, по кускам,
одну огромную карту генерировать не вариант.
Я сначала сгенерировал первый шум размерами например 100 х 100 пикселей,
потом я хочу сгенерировать еще один рядом с первым шумом, и соединить их без шва и так очень много раз.
Можно сказать генерация похожа на генерацию чанков майнкрафта.
Я переискал все, но нужного не нашёл.

Comment: у шума не может быть швов, он же шум.

Comment: @aepot видимо тут вопрос о том, как сгенерировать фрагмент карты шума в заданной области, так, чтобы он стыковался с соседними ранее-сгенерированными областями. // Автор, а как вы сейчас генерируете, каким кодом, как зерно задаете, и т.п.?

Comment: Использую простой симплекс шум , устанавливаю одно зерно, если надо могу генерировать новые , и при помощи функции генерирую шум дальше ничего не делаю потомучто не знаю

Comment: Покажи скриншот где видно 2 шума между которыми шов

Comment: Шум храниться в двух мерном масиве а потом я этот масив использую, я так сделал чтоби код бил компактней